# How can I turn this foreach push loop into a reducer function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I currently have a function that looks like this:

```js
export const getTags = (element: Record<string, any>) => {
  const tags: Record<string, any> = {};
  Object.keys(element).forEach((key: string) => {
    if (element[key] === true) {
      tags[key] = true;
    } else if (element[key] === false) {
      tags[key] = false;
    }
  });
  return tags;
};
```

You call it like this:

```js
const objToCheck = {
  foo: true,
  bar: false,
  baz: true,
  moo: [],
  boo: "hello",
}

const tags = getTags(objToCheck);
// returns: { foo: true, bar: false, baz: true }
```

I currently do this with quite an inefficient way by making an empty object and pushing to it, I was wondering if there was a different method like `reduce` to fill this object properly? Making the code a bit more clean.

The purpose of my function is to extract all values with booleans to a new object with the same key names and values.

Comment: Is the purpose of your function to return fields that have value `true` or `false`?

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic Yes, filter out those fields with their appropriate value, i'll edit the question to make it a bit more clear, thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer. Check if that is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good solution should look something like this:

```
export const getTags = (element: Record<string, any>) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(element)
      .filter(([key,val]) => val instanceof Boolean)
  );
};
```

we just filter out nonboolean values

Comment: Great solution! What do I do with the unused [key] though? The linter complains about it

Comment: it shouldn't, as we use 2nd param

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it says that it isn't an instance of a boolean

Comment: If I replace `instanceof` with `typeof val === 'boolean'` it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
export const getTags = (element: Record < string, any > ) => Object.entries(element).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    if (typeof key === "boolean") {
        acc[key] = val;
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: @Thimma check the updated solution. Mind the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
const objToCheck = {
  foo: true,
  bar: false,
  baz: true,
  moo: [],
  boo: "hello",
}

const result = Object.entries(objToCheck).reduce((acc, [key, value])=> { if([true, false].includes(value)) acc[key]=value; return acc; },{})
console.log('Result: ', result)
```

Comment: Nice one, is this also possible to do with array `curr` destructuring for eslint?

Comment: What do you mean? `curr` is current item in the array in each run

Comment: Eslint starts to whine if I use `curr[0]` and `curr[1]` to use array destructuring

Answer (score 0):

To modify the original object

```
const getTags = obj => {
    for(const key in obj) {
        if(typeof (obj[key]) !== 'boolean' ) delete obj[key]
    }
    return obj
}
```

To return a copy

```
const getTags = ({...obj}) => {
    for(const key in obj) {
        if(typeof (obj[key]) !== 'boolean' ) delete obj[key]
    }
    return obj
}
```

Comment: This modifies the original object, i want to return a copy with the new values

Comment: ok, just use a decostructor to return a copy.
`const getTags = ({...obj}) => { ...}`